# is default enough for a c'tor d'tor of a class with vector elements only?

Tags: c++, vector, constructor, destructor, copy-constructor

I have a class called `Item` that has two vectors as private elements

```
class Item
{
  private:
     std::vector<std::string> V;
     std::vector<std::string> E;
  public:
     Item(std::vector<std::string> V,std::vector<std::string> E): V(V),E(E){}
     Item(const Item& Item)=default;
     ~Item()=default;
      Item& operator=(const Item& Item)=default;

};
```

as you can see I've used the default for the d'tor, copy c'tor and operator =,
but is that enough or should I write bodies for each of them?

Comment: No, the default ones will do the job, see [rule of zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).  In fact, you don't need to code anything - the compiler will synthesise what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to write your own, but I'd modify the declaration of your constructor.

```
Item(const std::vector<std::string>& v, const std::vector<std::string>& e):V(v), E(e){}
```

Always prefer passing large object by const reference to by value. Passing object by value may causes unnecessary copy of object.

Comment: My bad, It can't  be changed. I should not mentioned the last comment.

Comment: so I don't have to add the `const` ?

Comment: You better, I was answering someone else who made comment but deleted then.

Comment: There was an wrong comment in my first answer, and someone pointed it out. I edited the answer currently thanks to him, and he deleted his comment.

Comment: If you omit const, which means passing object by reference, anyone creating instance of Item must be aware that the value of vectors passed to it may be changed after it instantiation. Perhaps they make copies of them before make an instance until they see the implementation of the constructor of Item.